# Highcharts: Legend not show

Tags: highcharts

I tried to make a chart using Highcharts 3.0. Have a look at `[http://jsfiddle.net/QL2Hn/][1]`

The problem is, why the chart legend only perform 2 pieces only? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well for me it lists all items, see this http://jsfiddle.net/QL2Hn/1/ but you need to set `showInLegend:true`

Comment: I solved the problem.

Total value must less than 5.

return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;


Thank you.